# SQL msAccess: list unfinished courses of a student

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a database like this

```
Table Result (StudentID,CourseName,Result)
Query Curriculumn (StudentID,CourseMustTake)

StudentID CourseName Result
0001      Chemistry   8

StudentID CourseMustTake
0001      Chemistry
0001      History
0001      Math
```

I need to list the courses that this student not enroll (in this case is History and Math)

I tried many ways but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.studentid, c.coursemusttake
from curriculumn c
left join result r on r.studentid = c.studentid
                  and r.coursename = c.coursemusttake
where r.studentid is null
```